# Vector bundle with a perfect pairing and ($\mathbb Z/2$, $SL_r$)-bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

I think this is a well knowing result but I can't find any reference,

Let $(E,q)$ be a vector bundle  with a non degenerated quadratic form $q:E\rightarrow E^*$ with trivial determinant, suppose that $q$ is symmetric (resp. skew-symmetric).

My question: Is there an equivalent of the stack of such couples with the one of  $(\mathbb Z/2, SL_r)$-bundle, with the action of $\mathbb Z/2$ on $SL_r$ is giving by $$g\rightarrow ^tg^{-1} \;(resp.\,\,g\rightarrow J_n\;^tg^{-1}J_n)$$

where $J_n=\begin{pmatrix}0&I_n\\-I_n&0\end{pmatrix}$

and how can one prove that (if the answer was yes!)?

thanks.

Comment: What is a $(\mathbb{Z}/2, SL_r)$-bundle?

Comment: $(\mathbb Z/2, SL_r)$bundle is just a principle $SL_r$ bundle with an action of $\mathbb Z/2$ on it that commutes (in some way) with action of $SL_r$. that's if $\mathbb Z/2=\{1,\phi\}i$ then $$\phi(g\cdot x)=\phi(g)\cdot \phi(x)$$

Comment: Then it is false -- in the symmetric case $\det(E)$ can be nontrivial.

Comment: I don't see the point, you are saying that $(\mathbb Z/2,SL_r)$ bundle can have a non trivial determinant? I will edit my question so!!

Comment: No, what I am saying is that there is no natural way to associate to a rank 2 (say) orthogonal bundle $(E,q)$ a $SL_2$-bundle, i.e. a rank 2 bundle with trivial determinant. How would you do that??

Comment: I thought that we just forget the orthogonal structure (forgetful functor)

Comment: I think I am wrong , because this just imply that the square of the det is trivial, sorry about that, editing the question...

Comment: If we have an automorphism $\rho$ of a linear algebraic group $G$, and I twist the action of $G$ over a $G$ bundle by $\rho$, is the new $G$ bundle is isomorphic to the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer my last question (last comment), if we give a $\rho:G\rightarrow G$ an automorphism of $G$, let us denote by $$E^\rho=E\times^GG$$ where the action of $G$ on itself is given by $\rho$, then generally $E^\rho$ is not isomorphique to $E$. It is when  $\rho$ is an interior automorphism. For exemple taking $\rho(g)=^tg^{-1}$, $G=GL_r$, then one can see easily $$E^\rho(\mathbb C^r)\cong E(\mathbb C^r)^*$$